# В Python нахождение корней методом дихотомии^ как избавиться от бесконечного ветвления?

Tags: python, математика

Пишу функцию поиска корня в уравнении с одной переменной методом дихотомии. И вот какая штука: суть метода - делим заданный отрезок оси Х пополам, что-то смотрим (либо сразу видим корень, либо продолжаем), потом еще раз пополам, еще и еще. До тех пор, пока не достигнем границ погрешности.
Разделив на любой итерации пополам, на что обращаем внимание: 1) на погрешность; 2) на другие моменты:

- если функция в середине отрезка равна нулю или меньше заданной погрешности, то корень есть середина отрезка;
- иначе если произведение функции в середине отрезка f(mid) и в его начале f(a) меньше нуля, то отрезок обретает уполовиненные границы от а до mid (и mid становится правой границей отрезка (то есть b=mid)). Делим дальше, пока не получим ноль в точке mid (f(mid)=0) или очередное значение не окажется меньше погрешности. Причем значение mid может становиться то границей а, то границей b (в зависимости от знака произведения функций f(mid) * f(a)<0 или f(mid) * f(a)>0).
- если же произведение функции в середине отрезка f(mid) и в его начале f(a) больше нуля, то отрезок обретает уполовиненные границы от mid до b. Продолжаем деление. Как в предыдущем пункте, значение mid может становиться то границей а, то границей b (пока не достигнет корня).

Пытаюсь реализовать это в коде. Что не так?

```
import numpy as np
# print(np.log(0))
def f(x):
    return 1.2-np.log(x)-4*np.cos(2*x)

# Функция метода дихотомии:
def dyhotomy(a,b, ε):
    assert a!=0,  'a равно 0'
    assert b!=0, 'b равно 0'
    args=np.arange(a,b,0.001)    # 0.001 – шаг; задаем сетку значений на отрезке
    root = 0
    # для совершенствования метода половинного деления (бисекции), который учитывает лишь изменение
    # знака функции,
    # совместим его с методом хорд, учитывающим также отклонение (абсолютную величину). Это ускоряет
    # приближение к корню (ведь чем меньше (по абсолютной величине) значение функции, тем ближе мы находимся к корню)
    korni = []
    for root in len(args):
        while abs(f(b)-f(a)) > ε:  # пока отрезок больше заданной погрешности, выполняем нижестоящие операции:
            mid = (a+b)/2                   # получаем середину отрезка
            if f(mid) == 0 or f(mid)< ε:    # если функция в середине отрезка равну нулю или меньше погрешности:
                root = mid                  # корень равень серединному значению
                korni.append(root)
                break
            elif (f(mid) * f(a)) < 0:       # иначе если произведение функции в середине отрезка на функцию в т. а <0
                b = mid                     # середина отрезка становится правой границей b
                mid = (a + b) / 2
                if f(mid) == 0 or f(mid)< ε:
                    root = mid
                    korni.append(root)
                    break
                elif (f(mid) * f(a)) < 0:
                    b = mid
                    # ... здесь можно снова ветвить и ветвить, но как остановиться? 
            else:
                a = mid                     #в другом случае - точка а
                if f(a) == 0 or f(a)< ε:
                    root = a
                    korni.append(root)
                    break
                # здесь тоже пойдет бесконечное ветвление: как встать на стоп? 
    #root = (a+b)/2 
    print(f'Корень функции согласно методу дихотомии находится в точке x = {root}')

dyhotomy(0.0001,200, 0.0009)
```

Comment: как минимум не так ``TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`` в строчке ``for root in len(args):``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `assert` лучше делать в самой функции, а не методе поиска корней.

```py
def f(x):
    assert x!=0, 'Аргумент не может быть равен нулю'
    return 1.2 - np.log(x) - 4*np.cos(2*x)
```

2. Вот так можно:

```py
def dyhotomy(a, b, eps):
    root = None
    while abs(f(b)-f(a)) > eps:
        mid = (a+b) / 2
        if f(mid) == 0 or abs(f(mid)) < eps:
            root = mid
            break
        elif f(a)*f(mid) < 0:
            b = mid
        else:
            a = mid

    if root is None:
        print('Корень не найден')
    else:
        print(f'Корень по методу дихотомии находится в точке x = {root}')
```

Или так (не сильно другое):

```py
def dyhotomy(a, b, eps):
    while abs(f(b)-f(a)) > eps:
        mid = (a+b) / 2
        if f(mid) == 0 or abs(f(mid)) < eps:
            print(f'Корень по методу дихотомии находится в точке x = {mid}')
            break
        elif f(a)*f(mid) < 0:
            b = mid
        else:
            a = mid
    else:
        print('Корень не найден')
```

Вызов:
`dyhotomy(0.0001, 200, 0.0009)`

---

Для общего развития вот рекурсивная функция:

```py
def rec_dyhotomy(a, b, eps):
    if abs(f(b) - f(a)) < eps:
        print('Корень не найден')
        return
    mid = (a+b) / 2
    if f(mid) == 0 or abs(f(mid)) < eps:
        print(f'Корень по методу дихотомии находится в точке x = {mid}')
    elif f(a)*f(mid) < 0:
        rec_dyhotomy(a, mid, eps)
    else:
        rec_dyhotomy(mid, b, eps)
```

Comment: в коде я добавил  `korni = []`, цикл `for root in range(len(args))` и добавление в список `korni.append(root)`
мне кажется, вместо break требуется прописать изменение значения root, только как его изменять, не очень понятно

Comment: вышло примерно так:
`def dyhotomy(a, b, eps):
    args = np.arange(a, b, 0.001)
    root = None
    korni = []
    for root in range(len(args)):
        while abs(f(b)-f(a)) > eps:
            mid = (a+b) / 2
            if f(mid) == 0 or abs(f(mid)) < eps:
                root = mid
                korni.append(root)
                break
            elif f(a)*f(mid) < 0:
                b = mid
            else:
                a = mid`